# RREF form of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Regarding the definition of a RREF matrix.We dont need the LEADING ( first non-zero element from the left ) to be a pivot ( 1 ), right ? We can have a messy matrix in RREF as long as it has column pivots with a 1 and rest of 0s, and also have only 1 pivot for each row. Is that right ?

Comment: RREF=Reduced Row Echelon Form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Reduced Row Echelon Form](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/echelonformmod.html) requires:

- All nonzero rows are above any rows of all zeroes.
- The leading coefficient of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it.
- *Every leading coefficient in a row is $1$* (pivot) and is the only nonzero entry in its column.[3]

The link above is to a university module on *reduced row echelon form*.

The requirements are more lax for "[row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)".

Compare and contrast examples of each, to better understand the difference.

Comment: So, this matrix  http://postimg.org/image/g0hxu9u2j/ is not in RREF, even if it is a RREF matrix with first and second column swaped ?

Comment: If i pick a matrix in RREF and then swap some columns, it suddenly becomes a non RREF matrix ? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: The image you posted is not in RREF, for one, there is a nonzero entry above the entry you refer to, and the entry you refer to is the leading entry, not equal to $1$.

Comment: One uses "row reduction" (Gaussian elimination), not column reduction.

Comment: Im quite not getting it, lets suppose i have a matrix that represents the system  x + 2y + 3z = 3  / y + 4z = 4 ... it is clearly in RREF. Then if i want a matrix that represents the same system but as : 3z + 2y  + x =3 / 4z + 4 = 4 . Then this same represents a different matrix, not in RREF ? I thought the importance of a RREF matrix was the coeficients of the variables, not the order in which the variables appeared in the equations. It makes no sense ...

Comment: If you represent the same system with different order of variables, you should be able to get a different RREF, if you did so with the first. But you have to be consistent from start to finish, and not swap columns in the middle of a row reduction. You can solve a system of equations without having reduced it completely to RREF. REF (second link) suffices.

Comment: flag
 
"If you represent the same system with different order of variables, you should be able to get a different RREF, if you did so with the first" hmhm i didnt understand it ...My doubt is putting a matrix into RREF then changing its columns ( and also changing the variables order in the vector x ) yields the same system as the original matrix RREF.So, why two systems that are the same ( same coeficients to all variables ) are represented by different classes of matrices ( one RREF and one non-RREF ) ? I thought the shape was not the important thing in RREF, but the coeficients of variables

Comment: The "different row reduced matrix" would necessarily be different because the coefficients of the original are relocated in the matrix. You should get the same *solutions* from either. Please glance over the links. I'm trying to be helpful here.

Comment: Glance over this link, please http://postimg.org/image/az449vr8x/. Im just trying to understand why an RREF is( and was ) defined not by the coeficients of the variables it generates, but simply by its shape ? I'm not even talking about the solution set that would be equal even if the coeficients wer edifferent, im talking about the specific of setup of coeficients that both RREF or the Different RREF and are the same.

Comment: Okay. My main question is : Why was the RREF defined not by the coeficients it generates on a system but by its form.Why is the RREF of matrix is more important than my Different RREF of a matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

In every row, the first nonzero entry is a pivotal 1. The pivotal 1 of a lower row is always to the right of the pivotal 1 of a higher row. In every column that contains a pivotal 1, all other entries are 0. Any rows consisting only of 0's are at the bottom of the matrix.